# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' for text summarization

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, summarization

```
from nltk.corpus import indian

sentence_score={}
#word=nltk.word_tokenize(text)
for sent in sentences:
    word_count_in_sentence = (len(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)))
    if word in wordfreq.keys():
        if sent not in sentence_score.keys():
            sentence_score[sent]=wordfreq[word]
        else:
            senetence_score[sent]+=wordfreq[word]
```

I m getting this error what do i do

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' for line 7 i.e    if word in wordfreq.keys():
```

Comment: We don't know what `word` is, but it might be a list rather that what you expect it to be...

Comment: Do not use `.keys()`, in a hashmap (dict) search is O(1), but searching in keys is linear. It seems that `word` or  `wordfreq` is a list, post your whole code please.

Comment: `if sent not in sentence_score:` is a LOT faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `defaultdict`

```
from nltk.corpus import indian
from collections import defaultdict

sentence_score=defaultdict(int)
#word=nltk.word_tokenize(text)
for sent in sentences:
    word_count_in_sentence = (len(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)))
    if word in wordfreq:
        senetence_score[sent]+=wordfreq[word]
```